# How can I access a numpy array column by name?

Tags: python, numpy

I´ve this numpy array:

```
array([((-24560412,   18229,   62, 198, 201, 5, -1,   6, 1, 239176.42401979),),
   ...,
   ((-25883120, -681084, 2583, 278, 201, 5,  1, 255, 1, 239424.37447651),)],
  dtype=[('point', [('X', '<i4'), ('Y', '<i4'), ('Z', '<i4'), ('intensity', '<u2'), ('flag_byte', 'u1'), ('raw_classification', 'u1'), ('scan_angle_rank', 'i1'), ('user_data', 'u1'), ('pt_src_id', '<u2'), ('gps_time', '<f8')])])
```

How can I access Z column values as an array, like points['Z']?

Comment: can you upload the data?

Comment: I think the dtype description and the data I posted is enough to show the situation, and the data is huge as well.

Comment: try `array_name['point']['Z']`

Comment: This is a straight forward structured array access - except that you have fields within a field.  `arr['point']` gives you a simpler structured array.

Answer (score 1):

you should be able to do:

```
array_name['point']['Z']
```

Comment: yes. You need to use code format when you write code. Use 4 spaces for the code line

Comment: @serafeim ohhh understand now, sorry, I rolled-back before I saw this because I was so confused. But I just rolled-back to your revision, thank you!

Comment: Notice that triple ticks (```) before and after a code block also works, which is probably more convenient for large blocks of code.